# Formal relationship between encryption and random number generators?

Tags: encryption, random-number-generator

Cryptographically secure random number generators seem to have similar properties to symmetric encryption:

- initial seed is permuted to produce a random numbers (*key and ciphertext*)
- given the seed, they produce a random number that cannot be linked back to the initial seed (*diffusion*)
- changing a single value in the seed results in multiple changes in the random number (*confusion*)

Is there a formal relationship between symmetric encryption and SRNGs?  I.e. is one a sub-set of the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes (loosely) and no (depending on your definition of a CSRNG).

A random number generator (restricting ourselves to Cryptographically Secure Random Number Generators) is actually a class of algorithms that produce a sequence of random numbers/bits - i.e. any sequence of numbers that is generated where the next part of the sequence cannot be predicted even with knowledge of the entire sequence to that point (with any non-negligible probability after a feasible amount of computation) can be a **CSRNG**, but a **CSRNG** can be constructed from cryptographic primitives in many different ways.

[Symmetric encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm) algorithms are generally either:

- Stream ciphers, which are formally modeled as a [Pseudo Random Generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_generator) or **PRG**. Technically these are usually a keystream produced by a PRG combined, e.g. by XOR, with the plaintext.
- Block ciphers, which are formally modeled as a [Pseudo Random Permutation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_permutation) or **PRP**.

Also in the general area of symmetric cryptography are [Pseudo Random Functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_function_family) or **PRFs**, which are often used as message authentication codes.

**CSRNG**s can be (and are) constructed from:

- **PRG**s - a **PRG** is already a **PRNG** by definition.
- **PRP**s - e.g. CTR_DRBG from [NIST SP 800-90A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NIST_SP_800-90A)
- **PRF**s - e.g. HMAC_DRBG from [NIST SP 800-90A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NIST_SP_800-90A). This also includes **PRP**s since a **PRP** is a pair of **PRF**s and you can just use the forward direction of the **PRP**.
- (and also) hash functions - e.g. HASH_DRBG from [NIST SP 800-90A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NIST_SP_800-90A)

In practice a deployed **CSRNG** also involves gathering of entropy from the environment (otherwise it would use a static or predictable seed value, which would break the **CSRNG** contract) and other defensive measures to prevent the reverse-engineering of the internal state of the RNG.

Ignoring the entropy/seeding/defensive measures, if you consider a **PRG** to be equivalent to a **CSRNG**, then you can show a formal relationship to other symmetric cryptographic primitives since a **PRG** can be trivially constructed from any **PRF** (simply by using the **PRF** to encrypt an incrementing counter value).

As an interesting aside, **PRG**s, **PRF**s and **PRP**s can all be converted into each other using formal (although not necessarily efficient) constructions.